# Length of the password field in html should not display the actual no. of characters in the password. How to achieve this?

Tags: html, passwords

I have a password field in a HTML page. Lets say my password is **abcdefgh**, and when i enter it in the password field, it shows as

[image]

Now, I want an added security like, it should not display the actual no. of characters in the password field. For example, lets say my password is **abc**, then the password box should not show 3 dots. Basically, what i mean is, the length of the password should not be inferred by seeing the password field. How to achieve it? Im a bit puzzled with this requirement. Pls help

Comment: If this is the place where the password is entered, I cannot see how this would work. How will you delete characters? How will you know what you've typed so far? The requirement does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

The password field should be blank when the page loads: you should certainly not be rendering the page with a value in it. Thus the blobs only appear as you actually type the password. If someone is looking over your shoulder to see the number of blobs, they could equally count the number of keystrokes you make couldn't they? Not sure what additional security you think you are getting here?

Also, if I'm typing a password, I quite like the visual indication of where in my password I am in case my fingers slip...

Comment: if one is quick at typing, then counting the no. of keystrokes by another person is difficult. Keeping that aside, is there any way such that for one character entered in the password box, it should display a random value(say2 or 3) blobs, thereby for password "abc", it shows 6 or 7 blobs?

Answer (score 1):

what else should be visibe in that case? nothing? in that case, i assume you could just [set the font-color to the background-color](http://jsfiddle.net/gc3q5/) or [make it transparent](http://jsfiddle.net/gc3q5/1/) (note: the later one is useful for gradient/images in the background but requires [rgba-support](http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba)).

the negative effect of this is you don't really see you're typing, so some (less technically adept) users migth think the form isn't working at all. As [David M](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10996960/288773) said, the amount of "additional security" might not be worth it.